# Is there any way in JUnit > 5.6.0 to load context before class execution condition evaluation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5

My goal is to execute tests in test class only when some spring property declared in `application-foo.properties` is equal to some constant.
I've tried to reach this by writing my own [ExecutionCondition](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.6.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.html) with annotation using it, and when I use it on `@Test` method it works fine. But using one on a test class leads to the problem: condition evaluates before Spring's context is up.

According to the docs:

> If an ExecutionCondition disables a test method, that does not prevent
> the test class from being instantiated.

*But what should I do if I want to?*

> Script-based condition APIs and their supporting implementations are
> deprecated with the intent to remove them in JUnit Jupiter 5.6. Users
> should instead rely on a combination of other built-in conditions or
> create and use a custom implementation of ExecutionCondition to
> evaluate the same conditions.

Since v5.6.0 the [@EnabledIf](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledIf.html) annotation was excluded. One of advantages of this one is `loadContext()` property, which allows to reach the goal of this topic, literally.
None of remaining annotations (e.g. [EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.6.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable.html)) contain even a tiny hint, how to reach it. And I haven't found any possibilities in the [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) as well.

I'll appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Maybe using the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` ? It is designed to load the Spring context application before the test starts. You of course may need to add specific configurations for your tests.

Comment: Have you considered using ˋEnabledIfˋ from Spring Testing? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit-jupiter-enabledif

Comment: @JorgeCampos In JUnit5 it is SpringExtension, and I use it implicitly via `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @johanneslink Yes, I did, but in fact this is the same deprecated annotation, and I do avoid using it :) Only if couldn't find more "honest" solution, I will use this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `@EnabledIf` from `import org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIf` was removed in JUnit 5.6.

There is also `@EnabledIf` from Spring Test `import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.EnabledIf` which is not deprecated and fits your use case.

```
@EnabledIf(
  expression = "#{systemProperties['your.property'].toLowerCase().contains('disabled')}",
  reason = "Disabled due to property",
  loadContext = true
)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

  // your tests

}
```

Let's say you have a property inside `application-foo.properties`:

```
flaky.tests.enabled = false
```

You can now conditionally run the tests with

```
@EnabledIf(
  expression = "${flaky.tests.enabled}",
  reason = "Disabled flaky tests",
  loadContext = true
)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("foo")
public class FlakyTest {

  // your tests

}
```

I tested it with Spring Boot 2.3.0 and it works fine without any deprecation warning.

Comment: Yeah, as this solution was shown in the comments, it works as expected. I started an issue on junit github, but since right now this is the only available solution, and since you described it in detail, I'll accept this answer, thank you very much.